# Jquery i18n plugin

Tags: jquery, internationalization

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n) jquery plugin for i18n.

Specifically, I want to use the data API in tags that must be translated but it's not working.

The alert shows "um" and the spans stay with "Um" and "Dois". I want a alert that shows "ONE" and the spans "ONE" and "TWO" respectively.

**Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>jQuery i18n Demo</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../src/jquery.i18n.js"></script>
<script src="../src/jquery.i18n.messagestore.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.i18n({
        locale: 'en'
    });

    alert($.i18n("um"));
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span data-i18n="um">Um</span>.
<span data-i18n="dois">Dois</span>.
</body>
</html>
```

**en.json**

```
{
"um": "ONE",
"dois": "TWO"
}
```

Has anyone ever use this?

Comment: What's "not working"?  What do you expect to see?  What do you see?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: There’s a nice tutorial here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3

Answer (score 0):

you are not ctually calling the en.json file. Follow the article below:

[How to Localize Your App With jQuery.I18n](https://dzone.com/articles/localize-your-app-with-jqueryi18n)